# Variables in templates

Tags: templates, variable

I want to update a variable based on my module. I can pass the variable from the main template (say A) to the embedded one(say B). But how can I retrieve this variable back in Template A after updating the variable from B.

Or is there any other way to use a variable in a template and gets updated from a module and the updated variable to be used in the proceeding exp: calls to the module?

When I try to update the variable, I always get the first assigned value.I think the issue is with the parse order.

If anyone knows, please help how to handle this requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embeds are normally parsed at the end.
You can try setting a variable with Stash.
In the main-template get the variable at process-end.

A better approach is to use stash to store your data
in the first place, and avoid an extra embed altogether.
https://github.com/croxton/Stash

```
// template1 -----------------------------------------
{exp:stash:set name="myvar"}value1{/exp:stash:set}
<h1>Test1</h1>
<p>The value is: {exp:stash:get name="myvar" process="end"}</p>
{embed="group/template2"}

// template2 -----------------------------------------
<h2>The embed</h2>
<p>myvar: {exp:stash:get name="myvar"}</p>
{exp:stash:set name="myvar"}value-embed{/exp:stash:set}

// output --------------------------------------------
Test1
The value is: value-embed
The embed
myvar: value1
```

Comment: Thanks. But one question. Can we get the updated variable at the beginning of each embedded templates? Since we are giving process = end, does the change for the value reflect at the end of html rendering? Please reply

Comment: i've editted the example. When you get:myvar in the embed before setting it again, you will get the current value. You can also set it as a snippet, pass it as a parameter to embed= and if you need it as a parameter for another tag in the embed, you can wrap that tag with a stash:get pair. Success

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify the variable in the process of template parsing, I would suggest creating a plugin that will utilize [EE Session cache](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#cache-access).

Depending on your exact needs, you may find [Low Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-variables) useful as well.